# using javascript/jquery/api to display something about concerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, object

I have this http://apis.is/concerts
which displays concerts that are upcoming in an API and I see that there are Images in it that I'm not able to display, I have made for loops that iterate through the objects and gets one by one and I see that every sixth one has an image link associated with it, How can I make that link for every sixth element in each object turn into an image?

I'm really sorry if this isn't written really well because i'm very bad at writing long stuff and explaining.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apis.is/concerts',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {


        var results = response["results"]

        for(var i in results) {
            for(var x in results[i]) {

                var the_text = results[i][x]
                $("#objects").append("<p>"+ the_text +"</p>")

            }
            $("#objects").append("<br>")
        }
    }


});
```

[image: Every Sixth Element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `the_text` contains the letters "jpg," append an image.  Otherwise, append the text:

```
if(/jpg/.test(the_text)) {
  $("#objects").append("<img src='"+ the_text +"'>");
} else {
  $("#objects").append("<p>"+ the_text +"</p>");
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apis.is/concerts',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {


        var results = response["results"]

        for(var i in results) {
            for(var x in results[i]) {

                var the_text = results[i][x]
                if(/jpg/.test(the_text)) {
                  $("#objects").append("<img src='"+ the_text +"'>");
                } else {
                  $("#objects").append("<p>"+ the_text +"</p>");
                }

            }
            $("#objects").append("<br>")
        }
    }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="objects"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my god! THANK YOU SO MUCH!, I've been trying to figure this out for ages and finally when I decided to post here someone instantly answers, god bless you Rick Hitchcock.

Comment: And what if some images happens to be `.png` ?

Comment: You could do `if(/jpg|png/.test(the_text))`.  If they're the only text to contain "https," you could simply do `if(/https.test(the_text))`.

Comment: The best is to have a quick look at the returned JSON structure to use it efficiently... ;)

Comment: Can't argue with that.  Gave you +1.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apis.is/concerts',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {


        var results = response["results"]

        for(var i in results) {
            for(var x in results[i]) {

                var the_text = results[i][x]
                if(/jpg/.test(the_text)) {
                  $("#objects").append("<img src='"+ the_text +"'>");
                } else {
                  $("#objects").append("<p>"+ the_text +"</p>");
                }

            }
            $("#objects").append("<br>")
        }
    }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="objects"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shortest way to code it.
Since you know the key (`imageSource`) you want...

I recommand you use the JSON keys to format your page correctly depending on the value...

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apis.is/concerts',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      var results = response["results"]

      for(i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
        $("#objects").append("<h1>"+ results[i].userGroupName +"</h1>");
        $("#objects").append("<img src='"+ results[i].imageSource +"'><br>");
        $("#objects").append("<p>Date of show: "+ results[i].dateOfShow +"</p><hr>"); 
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="objects"></div>
```